# Use of formControl inside mat-select in AngularMaterial

Tags: angular, angular-material, form-control

The following example i have taken from Angular Material

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

2)These is the second piece of code without formControl

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select  multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**ts-code**

```
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
}
```

3. i don't see Any difference in the first case and second case
4. Why Even should i use mat-select with formControl ,can anyone let me  know some use cases and how  my first code is different from second

Comment: In real-time, we do not have single form control on a form, generally, we use FormGroup with more than one form control, so get the updated value every time with all properties

Comment: @lostcoder, when you use FormControl (you can use `[formControl]` or, if you has a FormGroup `formControlName`) the values selected is store in the control.value (you can see if you write in html `{{topping.value}}`. futhermore, you can use instead of a formControl, `[(ngModel)]="variable"` and the values is stored in the variable. If you don't use anything you has a multiselect, but you don't has way to know what values are you selected

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, one general case where you would need a selected value(s) from MatSelect, in that case, your second example code will fail (you need an extra variable to hold the selected value)

so with the first example, you can easily get a selected value using

`toppings.value`

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgqzuy?file=src/app/select-form-example.html) is the working demo :)